# What's an example of a sequence that isn't bounded and whose only limit point is 0?

Tags: real-analysis

I was thinking of boundless sequences and I was wondering if there exists
an example of a sequence that isn't bounded and whose only limit point is 0?

Comment: $x_n=((-1)^n+1)n + \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: $x_n=n^{(-1)^n}$

Comment: Why not add answers instead of comments?

Comment: Any unbounded sequence already has one of the infinities as a limit point.

Comment: @A.S I take it the OP means "limit point *in $\mathbb{R}$*."

Comment: @Clement I think so too, but extended reals nicely unify treatment (any sequence has a limit point). If one would think in those terms, the OP's question would not even arise (as it would be - can a sequence have two limits points? Yes.).

Answer (score 4):

What about
$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if } n \text{ is even}\\
n &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
?